# Any reason to split up "cd" commands in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm cleaning up some old Windows batch files at work, and keep seeing lines like this:

```
D:
cd\
cd some\other\path\
```

is there any reason (compatibility with command.com maybe?) to not just write this as

```
cd /d d:\some\other\path\
```

Comment: I can't see any reason.  
IMHO the short variant is much more readable.

Comment: If there is no `some\other\path` directory, then the first method will leave you in the root of the D: drive, whereas the second will not do anything.

Comment: haha raymond chen chiming in on my first SO question, what are the odds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` doesn't actually change the working drive; it only changes the working directory *for* that drive.  That's why it's broken up that way.

An example might help:

```
C:\users\david>cd D:\some\path
C:\users\david>
```

Note the drive hasn't changed.

```
C:\users\david>D:
D:\some\path>
```

Now that D: is the "working disk", the working directory is changed to what you specified previously.

As you point out, `cd /d` will do both.  [UPDATE: I must have missed the `/d` when reading your original post :( -- sorry]

I believe you're correct -- there's no "good" reason not to use the one-liner -- other than compatibility with COMMAND.COM (which I'm pretty sure doesn't support the `/d` switch).  For this reason, I always create my script files with a `.cmd` extension if they depend on features not supported in COMMAND.COM.

A better alternative IMHO is to use `pushd` which behaves like `cd /d` -- and also gives you the ability to go back to wherever you were before (via `popd`).  You can even `pushd` to a UNC path (`\\server\share`) and Windows will create a temporary drive letter for you.  (Although I only found that feature this morning, and I'm running Win 7 Pro, so I'm not sure if it's available on older versions and/or Home editions.)

Comment: You didn't read the help of `CD` carefully. `cd /d` also changes the drive

Comment: Interesting.  But `pushd` and `popd` have been available since NT 4 ... I don't think the `/d` switch has been around that long.

Comment: That could be true, but I don't know anybody, who use such an old system

Comment: Also, `pushd` and `popd` give you a directory "stack" ... you can even `pushd` to a UNC path, and a temporary drive letter will be created for you.  (At least on Win 7 Pro.)

Comment: I doubt anybody's using NT 4 :) but I wanted something that would handle both drive and folder when I *was* using NT4, so I switched to `pushd` and never looked back.

Comment: I guess my question now becomes: when did the `\d` switch first show up? Not relevant to my specific case, but it'd be nice to note here for posterity... bonus points for a general reference that compares different versions of windows command line apps/keywords

Comment: @gruntlr: Do you think the modified dates of the batch files you were cleaning up could shed some light?

Comment: I found a reference to `cd /d` that seems to date back to Windows NT 3.5 ... all I can say is, if it was available back then, it wasn't very well documented. (I was an admin/support person then, and attended a number of Windows workstation & server administration classes -- which made a point of highlighting features in CMD.EXE not available in COMMAND.COM; I'm pretty sure this was never mentioned.)

Comment: @AndriyM: These things are a mess of the same cut-and-paste 'idioms' that have been around for who knows how long. Good thought though.  @ David: Thanks, just checked (don't know why i didn't before) and on windows xp sp3 command.com the /d switch does *not* work.